# Under what circumstance could switching tty's and entering commands freeze?

Tags: cache, freeze, ram, magic-sysrq

I noticed, that when booted from a live disc, and the RAM is filled up nearly, the live DVD starts being accessed far more often (probably due to exhausted and squished block cache) and switching tty's get delayed.

Commands, even simple commands such as 'echo test' get delayed.

```
$ echo test
_
```

Only **SysRq** is immune, also printing the SysRq+Space help, which lists the commands, happens instantly.

**What is the technical explaination?**

Comment: Could be, as you say, you are out of cache. Therefore everything is read from, slow, CD. However this would not apply to echo, if echo is a shell build it. What do you get if you run type echo.

Comment: @ctrl-alt-delor I will try it out next time I hit the RAM ceiling again (live DVD does not allocate swaps by default, which is actually good for a live DVD, due to testing suitability.).