# When would switching tty's in Linux not work?

Tags: tty

Linux should always allow switching between tty's.

But sometimes, for unknown random reasons, it just stops working.

Also on RAM overload when running from live disc, tty switching does not have the highest priority.

What do these situations have in common?
When exactly would the tty switching refuse to respond or lag?

Comment: When you've configured the system to spawn one tty...

Comment: This is pretty much https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/439767/ re-stated.